# Postgres view slow when combining 2 identical tables for query

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

Ok. 
I have a very large table used for statistics. I have a less data-dense version of the table also, which provides a backup and a way to clear down the main table. They are identical as far as columns, indexes, constraints.

The second table gets updated with specific anomolies from the main table, so if and when we clear down the data, the anomolies remain on record.

So I created a view which does a UNION between the 2 in order to query the data,

A cut-down version of the table...

```
ID
TIMESTAMP
KEY_1
KEY_2
```

There is a unique constraint on KEY_1,KEY2,TIMESTAMP

and an index on TIMESTAMP

If I query either table for a timestamp range and a single key_1,key_2, it uses the constraint.
If I query the view, it uses the timestamp index and thus reads through all key_1,key_2 values.
Even with another index TIMESTAMP, KEY_1, KEY_2 does it read using the TIMESTAMP index (the KEY_1 and KEY_2 are received from a JOINED table)

Thus, reading the VIEW for a lot of data takes ages as it scans 10000's more rows than reading the table directly.

It seems I cannot add a constraint to a view, so what can I do?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the query you are using and the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** (not just a "simple" explain). [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) or upload the plan to https://explain.depesz.com

Comment: Hi, I can't paste the explain in as I am prevented from showing publically, details of our database. Thus the generalised data above :(

Comment: You can upload the plan to https://explain.depesz.com/ and choose to anonymize the table names

Comment: Aha, ok useful.

Query from view
https://explain.depesz.com/s/gnoL

Query from single table
https://explain.depesz.com/s/6tfJ

Comment: You must have made a mistake. The slow query returns *way* more rows. The queries seem to be different.

Comment: The difference is literally a table name (1 of the 2 in the view) replacing the view
The view is simply a SELECT ..... from TABA JOIN SELECT ... FROM TABB
In the view, the query does not use the constraint, which returns only the rows it needs, but the TIMESTAMP index, which returns 10000's more rows.